# Get user_like and can_like for a post on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am trying to get user_like and can_like for a facebook post - using Facebook SDK on Android.

When I am setting the fields to limit the amount of data like below, I am unable to get those parameters.

```
fieldsBundle.putString("fields","likes.limit(4).summary(1),comments.limit(4).summary(1)");
```

However, when I do not specify the fields then I get the user_like and can_like within the Likes object. Limiting the data to a few entries is necessary so that my application is not overloaded with 1000 comments data.

Anyone having this problem? Is there any alternative to receive the number of comments for a post and can_like status at the same time? (keeping in mind that I don't want all the comments, like data, at once)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `can_like` field is only available via the `stream` FQL table's `like_info` object, and not via the Graph API.

You could request this for a certain `Post` via

```
select like_info from stream where post_id = "{post_id}"
```